# why 'addEventListener' only work with 'for loop'

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

why 'addEventListener' only work with 'for loop'?

my [codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/WyNJLp?editors=1111):

The for loop (working):

```
var isPurple = false;

for(var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++){
 btn[i].addEventListener("click", function()
 { if(isPurple){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  } else {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor =    "pink"; 
 }
  isPurple = !isPurple;

 }); }
```

With a class (doesn't work):

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
document.body.classList.toggle("purple");  
})
```

Regular class (doesn't work gives- "is not a function"):

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";

})
```

p.s 
Also I don't know why but also with for loop, it only work in the codepen, if I do it in it's console.

Comment: `var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")` => `var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]`;


When you use getElementsByTagName you get an array, so you must select with which button of the array you want to interact with.

Comment: Because `btn` is a **collection** of elements. Only elements themselves have the `addEventListener`  method.

Comment: @ХристиянХристов: Not an actual array but something *like* an array.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I used the exact code as in the leason and it worked there, that's what I don't understand

Comment: I know it's not an array there for I can't use the 'forEach' loop. also I don't understand russian :)

Comment: *"but I used the exact code as in the leason and it worked there, that's what I don't understand"* We can't help you without knowing anything about the lesson. The lessons setup could be totally different from yours. Anything could have changed. Presumably, `btn` refers to a single element there.